# How to decompose irregular time series?

Tags: r, time-series, decomposition, stl-decomposition

I have a time series with irregular time data from 2006 to 2020 including just the summer months (June, July, August). And I would like to get informations about trend, seasonality and mostly residuals.

- 2007-07-15  / 23.3132725761094
- 2007-07-24  / 27.5978287205735
- 2007-07-29  / 29.305232884511
- 2009-06-25  / 25.6451943453992
- 2009-06-27  / 34.6152556850167

Now,I did a complete time axis for each day over the years and merged my lst data.

```
library(forecast)
library(xts)

timestamps <- data$date

dataRep <- data.frame(timestamps= as.Date(c("2007-07-15","2007-07-24", "2007-07-29","2009-06-25")),
                      lst = c(23.3132725761094, 27.5978287205735, " ",25.6451943453992))

tstamp <- data.frame(x = seq(head(dataRep$timestamps,1),tail(dataRep$timestamps,1),by ="day"))
res <- merge(tstamp,dataRep,by.x="x", by.y="timestamps", all.x=TRUE)
tsData <-xts(res$lst,order.by =res$x)
```

Now, I wanted to apply my tsData to decompose() or slt(), but it didn't work and I got the following errors.

```
xts.stl <- stl(tsData,s.window="periodic")
```

Error: Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object

```
decompose(as.ts(tsData))
```

Error: Error in decompose(as.ts(tsData)) :
time series has no or less than 2 periods

Could someone help me please?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Your `head` and `tail` arguments are both length 1, whereas `head(data$date)` and `tail(data$date)` would each be six and may allow decompose to work. You may have used the length 1 for purposes of  a compact reproducible example. The decompose error is essentially saying this isn't enough data to go on.

Comment: I added a reproducable example. Thanks a lot in advance. Changing the length from 1 to 6 didn't work out, unfortunately.